# Checks whether an object already exists or not firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing an add ticket sale function

My db includes
User->uid->{name:abc,...., ticketSale:[{uidTicket: abcxyz, use: true //or false  }]}
Ticket->uidTicket->{nameTicket: qwer, ......}

User will take the list Ticket(table Ticket) and add them into User's ArrayTicket

The problem is check uidTicket already exist in User's ArrayTicket?

The code below that i know:

```
  firebase.firestore().collection("user").doc(Fire.shared.uid).update({ Ticket: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(uid) }).then(() => {
      alert('Get success')
    });
```

this code is usefull if ArrayTicket is Array uid, it can check uidTicket is already exist then can add or not

but myProblem is ArrayObject and how can i check UID ticket inside  User's arrayTicket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`array-contains` filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), which allows you to check if the `Ticket` array contains a certain UID.

Comment: It looks like it's selecting data, right? What I'm saying is adding a ticket object and just checking one of the object's properties is uidTicket to be able to add or update it like arrayunion.

Comment: The whole goal of using an array union is that you don't have to check if the item already exists in the array. Firestore will add the item if it's not in there yet, and won't add it if it already exists.